# shopping list item data type

Tags: mysql, list

I'm creating a Shopping List application for android and i'm using MySQL server.

I made an SQL table named 'shop_list' and it's columns are 'list_id', 'list_name', 'user_id' and 'item_ids'.
So each list ID is connected to a user ID so when a user is logged on he can see only his lists.

My problem is that I don't know which data type to use for the 'items' column.
I have a list of items that I want users to choose their items from there, so I thought about using SET data type, and fill it with all available item IDs from 'items' table but I don't know how to do that.

I also thought about using a VARCHAR and just parsing the text but i'm afraid it's not long enough (in case the user added many items to the list).

Please advice me what can I do to make this work.
Thanks!

EDIT:
I have two tables: `'products'` and `'shop_list'`.
this is what `'products'` looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE 'products' (  
'id' int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
'productname' varchar(45) NOT NULL,  
UNIQUE KEY 'id' ('id')  
)
```

Now what I need is to make another table that saves the lists users creates.
I thought about something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE 'shop_list' (  
'list_id' int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
'list_name' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
'user_id' VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL /*automatically insert the logged-on user ID*/  
'products' /*I need this column to contain all the item IDs from 'products' table, according to the user's choice*/  
);
```

My problem is how to set the products column is `shop_list` table (By picking from SET data type or any other idea I didn't think of...)

Thanks again

Comment: you can use `VARCHAR(5000)` From referece: _The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 65,535_

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm just thinking this method might be pretty buggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an `item` table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE items(
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   description TEXT,
   createdAt DATETIME,
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

This table should contain all items not just those a user has added to their list.

It goes without saying that this is a simple example and that you should include any information you need about each item.

After creating this, you should create another one that will match items from the `item` table with a list from the `shop_list` table:

```
CREATE TABLE list_item(
   id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
   listId INTEGER NOT NULL,
   itemId BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY(id),
   FOREIGN KEY(listId) REFERENCES shop_list(id),
   FOREIGN KEY(itemId) REFERENCES item(id)
);
```

Of course you will need to change the data type of `listId` to match yours

Comment: @Nickleby First of all, your `products` table needs a primary key, so do this: `ALTER TABLE products ADD PRIMARY KEY(id)`
Read my post carefully, you need to create another table that will connect the products with the lists. You can't store all the products of a list in a single line. No data type is good enough for this. The best practice is to create a separate table

Answer (score 0):

Make this a separate table:

shop_list

- list_id
- list_name
- user_id

shop_list_item

- list_id
- item_id

Comment: That I did, my problem is how to insert the values properly

Comment: First `insert into shop_list(list_name, user_id) values ('My list', 100); `, then `insert into shop_list_item(list_id, item_id) values (last_insert_id(), 12345), (last_insert_id(), 23456), (last_insert_id(), 34567);`

Comment: Oh got you, and then retrieve data from both tables, nice. but isn't there an easier way achieving that?

Comment: Easier? What's difficult about it?